# how to put delimiters in text files using command or script

Tags: linux

i have a text file in which i want to put delimiters after certain characters ( fix),.
like put a delimiter (any like ,) after `1-3` character than `4` than `5` than `6-17 .....`

files looks like this (original)

```
22503003673916972040504700538884720121008175657358045042677480191000000919046068826
```

and i want file like this

```
225,0,3,003673916972,0405047005388847,20121008175657,3580450426774801,91,000000919046068826,
```

please suggest any command or script that will do this work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I'd use python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

a='22503003673916972040504700538884720121008175657358045042677480191000000919046068826'

# python strings are 0-indexed, just
# add the indexes below
delim=[2, 3, 4, 16]
A=""

for n, i in enumerate(a):
    if n in delim:
        A+='%s,' % i
    else:
        A+=i

print A
```

output:

```
$ ./delim.py 
225,0,3,003673916972,040504700538884720121008175657358045042677480191000000919046068826
```

It can also be written quite terse using list comprehension:

```
>>> "".join([i+',' if n in delim else i for n, i in enumerate(a)])
'225,0,3,003673916972,040504700538884720121008175657358045042677480191000000919046068826'
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed "s/^.\{4\}/&,/;s/.\{6\}/&,/;s/.\{8\}/&,/;s/.\{20\}/&,/;s/.\{37\}/&,/;s/.\{52\}/&,/;s/.\{69\}/&,/;s/.\{72\}/&,/;s/.\{91\}/&,/" filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the head and tail command in bash script. At firt see the mannual in terminal `man head` and `man tail` you will understand in details.
I want to show my logic I don't know it is good idea or not.
Lets say your file name is **original.txt** 
Now read first 3 character like this

```
var1=$(head -c 3 original.txt)
```

First three character is store in variable var1 i.e 225 store that value in another file lets say **final.txt** by putting delimiter. Now this time read first four character like below

```
var2=$(head -c 4 original.txt)
```

First four character is store in variable var2 i.e 2250 echo it in a temp file `echo var2>temp.txt`

But this time you have to use tail like below

```
var3=$(tail -c 1 temp.txt)
```

here last character is store in variable var3 i.e 0 ,append this var3 in file final.txt using delimiter. This time final.txt must look like this `255,0,`

Next character can be done similar to like above. We can also do this using loop.